# onmouseover is not working in jquery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have developed android phonegap app using html and jquery.I need to show tooltip for textbox.so i tried using mouseover in jquery,but its working like normal click event.After i click the textbox i am getting the alert.I have tried in javascript also.

Here is my code:

```
    $('#text').qtip({
       content: "element",
       show: 'mouseover',
       hide: 'mouseout'
    });


 <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="first"/>
 <script src="jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please kindly help me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any mouse on the Phone, so there can not be any "mouse over". I know for iOS there is a movement event, maybe something similar on Android that could be useful.

Comment: This maybe helps you http://backtothecode.blogspot.se/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html